# Unable to run Ruby file on Windows 8?

Tags: ruby, file, ide

I'm running a Ruby file on Windows 8.

My computer doesn't know which program to run my Ruby file with. I have Ruby installed, but it won't let me open it without an IDE. My team members run it regularly from the command prompt and don't want us using IDEs.

Any thoughts on how to get it to run? Or should I ask my team members?

Comment: What’s the problem with `ruby myfile.rb` from the file’s directory? Would you provide the errors you see, at least?

Comment: Most non-Windows open-source language developers are used to not using IDEs, and are very comfortable at the command-line. The IDE can get in your way and offers nothing when running code, only when developing it, so their recommendation to not use it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby files aren't really "opened" as much as executed. Basically, the workflow is not to double click on a `.rb` file but rather to run it in the command line. Let's say you have a file called

```
hello.rb
```

To run this file you'd do:

```
$ ruby hello.rb
```

Now, as far as being sure you have ruby installed. Make sure that when you type

```
$ ruby --version
```

You get back a version number. Otherwise, it may not be installed. If that's the case, take a look here: http://rubyinstaller.org/

Also, if you want to edit a ruby file I'd recommend you use a text editor. On windows even notepad will do. Just right click on the file and select "Open with notepad" (I think). I've heard good things about http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

**Please note, I haven't used Windows in years so I may be a tad off on some points.**

Comment: Well, he could associate the file extension to be opened by the Ruby interpreter he's installed. So, it would allow for the double-clicking functionality inside windows.